# In dplyr groups, how can I select a group that has a combination of a specific value with only ONE other of multiple values

Tags: r, dplyr, combinations

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
Group  Company
1      A
1      XX
1      A
1      XX
2      XX
2      A
2      XX
2      B
3      B
3      B
3      XX
3      A
4      C
4      C
4      XX
4      XX
```

It's actually bigger with more columns and rows and values, but the problem I want to solve involves these two columns for now.

Now, what I would like to achieve is, for each **Group**, to replace **Company** in the following way:

If XX exists in a Group, together with any other **unique** Company value, then Company should be replaced with this unique value. Like so:

```
Group  Company
1      A
1      XX
1      A
1      XX
```

Should become:

```
Group  Company
1      A
1      A
1      A
1      A
```

If any **Group** contains more than 2 unique values for **Company**, including "XX", then this group's **Company** value should remain unchanged, like so:

```
Group  Company
2      XX
2      A
2      XX
2      B
```

I am trying to achieve this using dplyr, I managed to do what I wanted but for only one value of **Company**, like so:

```
result <- df%>%
group_by(Group) %>%
mutate(final = ifelse(Company %in% c("A", "XX"), 1,2)) %>% 
summarize(test = mean(final))

result$final <- ifelse(result$test== 1, "A", result$Company)
```

I could probably do this with a loop, but I am pretty sure this would not be the best way to do it.

Is there a clean way to do this with dplyr ? (of course other solutions are more than welcome)

The final dataframe would then look like this:

```
Group  Company
1      A
1      A
1      A
1      A
2      XX
2      A
2      XX
2      B
3      B
3      B
3      XX
3      A
4      C
4      C
4      C
4      C
```

Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way with `dplyr` -

```
df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(
    Company = case_when(
                ("XX" %in% Company) && (n_distinct(Company) == 2) ~ Company[Company != "XX"][1], 
                TRUE ~ Company
              )
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 16 x 2
   Group Company
   <int> <chr>  
 1     1 A      
 2     1 A      
 3     1 A      
 4     1 A      
 5     2 XX     
 6     2 A      
 7     2 XX     
 8     2 B      
 9     3 B      
10     3 B      
11     3 XX     
12     3 A      
13     4 C      
14     4 C      
15     4 C      
16     4 C
```

Comment: Thank you, this works brilliantly! I need some more practice with the extra dplyr verbs. Could you please explain the second condition : TRUE ~ Company ?

Comment: Anything that doesn't meet condition 1 is taken care of by the second condition since the second condition set to `TRUE` by default. In this case the company values remain unchanged when condition 1 is not satisfied.

Comment: Right! I was thinking of terms of if_else statements. That is a case... So indeed :) Thank you so much!